# php-pdf -table creation

Tags: php

I am trying to create a table with fpdf
but the inputs of my table is quite big so its not fitting in one cell and i dont know how to push that data into next line without distorting the table structure.

I tried using multicell to..which did not work.

i used this code

```
function table_2($header,$data)

{
    // Colors, line width and bold font
    $this->SetFillColor(255,0,0);
    $this->SetTextColor(255);
    $this->SetDrawColor(128,0,0);
    $this->SetLineWidth(.3);
    $this->SetFont('','B',5);
    // Header
    $w = array(8, 90, 90);
    for($i=0;$i<count($header);$i++)
        $this->Cell($w[$i],7,$header[$i],1,0,'C',true);
    $this->Ln();
    // Color and font restoration
    $this->SetFillColor(224,235,255);
    $this->SetTextColor(0);
    $this->SetFont('');
    // Data
    $fill = false;
    foreach($data as $row)
    {
        $this->Cell($w[0],6,$row[0],1,0,'L',$fill);
        $this->Cell($w[1],6,$row[1],1,0,'J',$fill);
        $this->Cell($w[1],6,$row[2],1,0,'J',$fill);
        //$this->Cell($w[2],6,number_format($row[2]),'LR',0,'R',$fill);
        //$this->Cell($w[3],6,number_format($row[3]),'LR',0,'R',$fill);
        $this->Ln();
        $fill = !$fill;
    }
    // Closing line
    $this->Cell(array_sum($w),0,'','T');
}
```

can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use this lib http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/. It allows to convert html+css into pdf file. It is based on fpdf. I used it to generate pdf-file with about 1000 pages. It is awesome.

I shope it will helpfull. I not - sorry.